# Remove ArrayList Object from Memory

Tags: java

I have a bunch of Objects in an `ArrayList`, if I call `ArrayList.remove(object)` Do I need to do anything else to remove the object from memory? I am adding and removing objects from this list at a fairly very quick pace, so if it doesn't get removed from memory I it will start taking up space and start to slow down the Game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-** When you call `ArrayList.remove(object)`, you just remove the objects from the `List` **Not from the Memory**.

**-** It will depend on the `Garbage Collector` to decide when its gonna remove the object from the heap, under normal circumstances its an object is ready for garbage collection as it has **No reference to it anymore.**

**-** There is a classic example of why `String` which is an object in Java **should not be used for storing password** instead `char[]` should be used.

See this link...

[Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords/8881376#8881376)

Answer (score 1):

Java does automatic garbage collection.  So once an object is no longer referred to, it **can** be deleted, that doesn't mean it will be deleted.  Garbage collection is automatic, you can ask that it be done by calling System.gc() however this is just a sugestion to run it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to do anything else, as long as that's the only place that's referencing the object. Welcome to the joys of a garbage-collected language! Java will clean up old, unreferenced objects when it decides that it needs to reclaim some memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you chew through the heap quick enough, you can nudge the gc along with some jvm args ... we have an app that handles billions of operations a day and have tuned it heavily with the  [ergonomic gc settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) I'd encourage you to play with the adaptive size policy, and the max pause setting primarily.  Run the program with a profiler exercising the arraylist as you normally would for a while (several minutes) and see how the ambient state of the various heap generations looks.  You may end up having to also tweak the [memory allocations to generations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129044/java-heap-terminology-young-old-and-permanent-generations).

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList.remove removes the object from the array, and then if the object is not referenced to by any other objects, the GC will delete that object.