# Difference between Old generation and Tenured generation

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, disposing

Now I trying to understand fundamental concepts of java garbage collection.

I have read a lot articles about it.

And somewhere I see `old generation` and somewhere `tenured generation`. Description is very similar.

looks like one of them is the evolution of second.

Can you provide more information about this topiс?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129044/java-heap-terminology-young-old-and-permanent-generations

Comment: @Nagakishore Sidde you can see that I have already read this topic and post comment to the question. But my question a bit different

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've always regarded the Old Generation and Tenured Generation as the same thing, and this diagram from http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html backs that up.

[image]

if you Google Old generation versus Tenured you'll also find lots of people saying things like "Tenured (Old) Generation" -like  http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue092.html

Occasionally, I've seen people regard Old Generation as the Tenured + Permanent Generation but I've never seen any official confirmation for that.

Comment: *"... but I've never seen any official confirmation for that."* - Not surprising.  I don't think is is true.  In Java 7 and earlier, the Old generation and Permgen were separate.  And in Java 8 and onwards, permgen is replaced with the "metaspace"

Comment: @Disco 3 and what the reason to call same thing by different names?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway the Permanent Generation is moved to native space and is out of GC competence in Java 8. So now it seems to be the same.