# Purpose of the parameters XXMaxPermSize, vmargs, Xms and Xms in eclipse.ini, what do they do

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, out-of-memory

I was developing an App. I had to modify my eclipse.ini so I wanted to know the purpose and meaning of these parameters `XXMaxPermSize, vmargs, Xms and Xms`, in order to correctly use them.
I am using eclipse 3.8 on ubuntu 14.04, with java 7.

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Comment: Everything following -vmargs is an argument to the Java VM and is documented in the Oracle Java documentation. Everything before -vmargs is documented [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Greg says, everything after -vmargs are VM args which are supplied to the JVM when an application starts. -Xmx is the maximum heap size, -Xms is the initial heap size, and the launcher.XXMaxPermSize is presumably an argument to the eclipse executable. This increases the size of the permagen space. I suspect this argument only really works pre java 8, as permagen was eliminated in 8.

Comment: permagan - Permanent Generation (non-heap): The pool containing all the reflective data of the virtual machine itself, such as class and method objects. With Java VMs that use class data sharing, this generation is divided into read-only and read-write areas. from http://stackoverflow.com/q/2129044/3879470

Answer (score 2):

Java official documentation will help you
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Comment: can you summarize those parameters in one line?

Comment: Like Greg says, everything after -vmargs are VM args which are supplied to the JVM when an application starts. -Xmx is the maximum heap size, -Xms is the initial heap size, and the launcher.XXMaxPermSize is presumably an argument to the eclipse executable.

Comment: add that as an answer, and XXMaxPermSize 256 m what does that do?